# doing a regex on an array and storing in another array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

this is my code that extracts the date "2016-06-13" from the string "ffg_LTE_2016-06-13"

```
$re = '/(\d{8})|([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})|([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})/';
$str = "ffg_LTE_2016-06-13";
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
$date=$matches[0];
print_r($date);
```

Now what I want to do is do somthing like this in a for loop but I am having issues with storing the result in an array. What I want to do is the same as above but do it on each elememt in the array.

```
$files=["ffg_LTE_2016-06-13","ffg_LTE_2016-06-14"];

foreach ($files as $value) {
    print_r("<br>".$value."<br>");
}
```

So my end result would be

$files_2=["2016-06-13","2016-06-14"];

here is my [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ez3a-jptc)

Comment: why not jiust explode on the underscore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<?php

    $files=["ffg_LTE_2016-06-13","ffg_LTE_2016-06-14"];
    $re = '/(\d{8})|([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})|([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})/';

    $results = [];
    foreach ($files as $value) {
        preg_match($re, $value, $matches);
        $results[] = $matches[0];
    }
    print_r($results);

?>
```

It just loops through `$files`, pushes the first match into the array `$results`, and prints out `$results`.

Comment: tks, can you just briefly explain this `$results[] = $matches[0];` as I think I was tring to do this `$results=$matches[0]`or `array_push($results,$matches[0]);` but maybe I should do this `array_push($results[],$matches[0]);` I was basically missing the `[]` in `results`

Comment: @HattrickNZ `$results[] = $matches[0];` is equivalent to `array_push($results,$matches[0]);` as state on the manual page http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php